# Tooltip для Point

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть коллекция точек, как мне создать для каждой точки подсказку с выводом её координат?

Была такая идея:

```
foreach(var point in pointCol.Points)
{
    point.Tooltip = point.X + point.Y
}
```

Но такой вариант не работает, для point ничего подобного нет. Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Коллекция точек выстраивает Polyline.. Нужно при наведении на точку выдавать в подсказке её координаты.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17172327/5045688 - это не оно?

Comment: `Point` - это не контрол, а структура, у нее есть только X и Y. Она даже не точка, а просто координаты точки, два числа типа `double`.